# how to Fetch value of the radio button in django

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

i am making a quiz app

this is my html file

```
 {% for question in questions %}
<p>Q){{question.name}}</p>

<input type="radio" value="1" name="{{question.id}}">{{question.option1}} 
<input type="radio" value="2" name="{{question.id}}">{{question.option2}}
<input type="radio" value="3" name="{{question.id}}">{{question.option3}}
<input type="radio" value="4" name="{{question.id}}">{{question.option4}} 

{% endfor %}
```

in my database i have my correct answer store with the name correct_option

this can be the code for checking the score

```
{% if question.correct_option == ? %}
{% score=1 %}
{% endif %}
```

for writing this i need to find out what did user select so
what should be written in place of '?'

Answer (score 1):

While it's certainly possible to implement a form like that, I'd recommend using Django's built in form system. [Here's a link to the docs about it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/)

If you weren't going to use the built in system however, you'd need to use a form tag `<form method='post'></form>` and create a view that could handle the users POST request for after the user has submitted their answers

Comment: can you please be particular about which documentation should i refer to...i am a noobie so i dont know much about it.

Comment: For sure, try [this link out](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/)  instead. It should help you understand the basics better